# Counter-example to show that difference doesn't hold in ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I=\left \langle a \right \rangle$ and $J = \left \langle b \right \rangle$ be ideals in a ring A. Show that $I\cdot J = \{xy\mid x\in I,y\in J\} $ is an ideal in A and $I\cdot J = \left \langle ab \right \rangle$.

I can show that the product rule for ideals hold for $I\cdot J$ (i.e. $xij \in I\cdot J $ where $x \in A$ and $ij \in I\cdot J $). But i'm stuck trying to show that  $ij - i'j'$ is in  $I\cdot J$. I'm thinking that this isn't valid for all cases, but I can't find a counterexample (I tried to use ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ for that but it didn't work).

Comment: That only holds if the ring is commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true since $I$ and $J$ are principal ideals. If $i, i' \in (a)$ and $j, j' \in (b)$, write $i = ra, i' = r'a, j = sb, j' = s'b$. Then $ij - i'j' = (ra)(sb) - (r'a)(s'b) = (rs - r's')ab \in (ab)$.

More generally, if $I = (a)$ is principal and $J = (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$, then $I \cdot J = (ab_1, \ldots, ab_n)$.

Comment: Thanks @zcn! Reading your comment the mistake became clear, I forgoto to define $i = ra$ and $j=sb$.